# Displaying & Modifying Diagrams / Flowgraphs in PyQt GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, diagram, dia

Essentially what I would like to do is draw a circuit diagram in a PyQt based on input given from another part of the GUI.  My first thought was to simply use graphical tiles, and switch them out as pixmaps based on the input, but that is pretty clunky.

I suppose finding a way to actively display [dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) diagrams in a frame of the GUI would work as well.

Regardless, how would you recommend going about doing this?  Is there as easier way?

Thanks!

Edit: Does anyone have experience with any of the following?

- http://code.google.com/p/pydot/
- http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/
- http://code.google.com/p/yapgvb/
- http://live.gnome.org/Dia/Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone that needs to go down this route in the future, the best option was definitely pydot.  Easy to use, and pretty full-featured.  Way to go, Graphviz.

Comment: Would you recommend pydot to use as library for creating an interactive block scheme environment? Looks like it can generate nice output pictures, but can it also display schemes in a window?